# Show / Hide Views while clicking a BUTTON in RemoteViews( Custom Layout ) for NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working in FCM notification in which I faced a strange issue due to that I was unable to proceed further.

[image]

Above is the custom notification I have created. I need to show/hide bottom grey color view respective to "Accept" or "Reject" button click.

I can only create a Pending intent while clicking the Accept or Reject button using below code

```
    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notifications);

  // reject button click intent
    Intent rejectIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent rejectIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, rejectIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // approve button click intent
    Intent approveIntent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
    PendingIntent acceptIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, approveIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            // Set Ticker Message
            .setTicker("notification received")
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            //.setWhen(0)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            // .setContent(remoteViews)
            // Set Title
            .setContentTitle("App Name")
            // show big notification hint when app is open
            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            // Set Text
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            // Set Sound
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            // notification button 2
            .addAction(rejectAction)
            // notification button 3
            .addAction(approveAction)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            .setContent(remoteViews);
```

But how to handle View. Any help will be a great help for me.

IS THIS POSSIBLE SCENARIO...

Comment: As part of your `PendingIntent` processing the accept or reject actions, you would need to raise a `Notification`, with your revised look, with the same notification ID (so it replaces the existing notification).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the tip. But the way you suggested is not a regular or proper way to handle. Replacing and showing the same is a type of workaround. Need more accurate solution.

Comment: "But the way you suggested is not a regular or proper way to handle" -- um, well, yes it is. "Replacing and showing the same is a type of workaround" -- no, that is how you update a `Notification`.